# Можно ли с помощью python selenium узнать другие локаторы элемента, когда известен только один?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Например есть определенная кнопка на сайте у которой есть локатор:

`//div[2]/span/span/span/span/span/span`

Но также у нее есть и другие неизвестные скрипту в момент работы:

`(//a[contains(@href, '/assignments/6234302/go')])[2]`

`.cards__col:nth-child(2) .task__type`

Можно ли как-то их определить скрипту?

Comment: Не "локатор", а XPath.

Comment: 1. XPath - это тип локатора

Comment: Локатор - это объект которые находит элементы по запросу, а сам по себе локатор - не запрос.

Comment: Понял, а по вопросу есть что-нибудь?)

Comment: Если вам требуется определить элемент по селектору, то скорее всего это то, что вам нужно: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cards__col:nth-child(2) .task__type[href*='/assignments/6234302/go']")`

Comment: У меня другая проблема, требуется чтобы скрипт во время работы у кнопки по XPath смог получить css_selector по которому я также мог обратиться к этой кнопке

Comment: Ну сам по себе XPath который вы представили не содержит много информации, из него можно слепить CSS селектор по типу такого: `div:nth-child(2) > span > span > span > span > span > span`, но не более того. Можно регулярными выражениями, или можно самому пройтись циклом и сделать селектор.

Comment: Ну ладно, спасибо за помощь:D